# Стоит ли освоить C после C++?

Tags: c++, c

Уже 2 год программирую на C++, в основном десктоп приложения под windows/linux. А есть ли смысл осваивать C после C++. Может язык C даст что-то полезное?

Comment: А С++ без С освоить не получится в принципе. Ведь С - это подмножество С++.

Comment: Когда ты освоишь C, этот замечательный язык, тебе C++ покажется языком с кучей не нужной функциональщицей. сможешь приложения на gtk писать. хотя на gtk можно и на c++ писать.

Comment: @user7860670, это было давно) языки похожи, но никто ничьим подмножеством не является

Comment: короче не нужно. В плюсах тебе будет еще что изучать лет на 10 вперед.

Comment: Да. Изучишь за неделю и будешь все что надо спокойно на нем писать по памяти, не обращаясь к справочникам (интернету)